# Nautilus answers need to be moved

Tags: discussion, answers

I think I perhaps hit the bounty trigger too early but ...

- [How to add "Refresh" option to right click menu in Lubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156201/how-to-add-refresh-option-to-right-click-menu)
- [How to get a "refresh" right click action?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343719/how-to-get-a-refresh-right-click-action)

The Lubuntu one has answers for Nautilus ... but Lubuntu doesn't ship Nautilus, I think those answers should be moved to the newer question and then the older question should be more like "How do I add a refresh option to pcmanfm" (or whatever the file manager is in Lubuntu)

Comment: An answer has been added for Lubuntu (PCManFM), which works for versions 12.04, 12.10, and 13.04.  Also the old answer also works for Nautilus.  So I agree with you, there should be 2 questions, and answers.

Comment: How about one about "nautilus in unity/ubuntu" and "nautilus in lubuntu/lxde"? changing the title and all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I flagged [those answers](https://askubuntu.com/a/157536/147044) as inappropriate, and the answer was:

> declined - The OP seems happy with the answers. And we can't "move" answers.

So, case closed.